# Entity Framework Core - Detach related entities except if they are a parent entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core, entities

The problem I'm trying to overcome is that I'm trying to detach all entities in DbContext.ChangeTracker if they are not the principal entity that I'm changing to avoid inserting child items of a parent entity when inserting the parent.

The reason to why I want this kind of behaviour is because we're migrating from the existing codebase to Entity Framework. I need to implement an interface that is currently used in the existing codebase as follows:

```cs
parentRepository.InsertItemAsync(parentEntity, cancellationToken);
childRepository.InsertItemAsync(childEntity, cancellationToken);
```

Changing all the existing codebase is not an option so I need to make my implementation of the interface behave the same way that the code that already exists.

I came up with a solution but it only works on parent entities. I detach all entities in the DbContext.ChangeTracker that are not of the type of the entity managed by that repository. Like this:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Detach all entities that are not managed by this repository.
/// </summary>
private void DetachRelatedEntities()
{
    EntityEntry[] entities = _dbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries().ToArray();

    foreach (EntityEntry? e in entities)
    {
        var entityType = e.Entity.GetType();

        if (entityType != typeof(T))
            e.State = EntityState.Detached;
    }
}

// <T> is the type of the entity that the IRepository<T> manages.
```

The problem is that when it is a child entity, it detaches its parent because it meets the condition of the if, and when the parent is detached the childs are automatically detached by Entity Framework.

Is there a way that I can make the condition more strict and it only applies when "entityType" is not a parent entity of "T"? Or is there a way to detect that the entity "T" has a FK and get the type of the entity of the FK?

Since this may be hard to understand without seeing the code, I describe here one of the methods I've implemented and what I'm trying to achieve:

```
public async Task InsertItemsAsync(IEnumerable<T> items, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    if (items.ToList().TrueForAll(i => !Set.AsNoTrackingWithIdentityResolution().Any(s => s.Id == i.Id)))
    {
        Set.AddRange(items);

        DetachRelatedEntites(); // This is what I'm trying to achieve and its not working. I want to detach all entities that are not "T" entity so I can add them later separately.

        await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);

        DetachEntities(); // Here I detach all entities to avoid "Entity is being tracked by another context". This is already working.
        return;
    }

    throw new InvalidOperationException($"An item of {nameof(items)} already exists in the DB.");
}
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Definitely try `context.ChangeTracker.Clear()` after each `SaveChanges()`

Comment: If I do that after SaveChanges() it will detach all entities but I want to detach entities before SaveChanges () and only the related entities. So for example, I have a father entity and a child entity: I'm inserting father entity and I don't want father inserting child automatically I want to be able to do it separately.

Comment: @ArenDevel you could remove *all* code from `InsertItemsAsync` and leave only `SaveChanges`. This method will save *all* tracked changes and nothing more. Calling it the first time will save both parent and children. Calling it a second time will do nothing. If you want to save *detached* entities you can use `Update` on the root item. This will start tracking the root and children either as Added or Modified, depending on their PK values - entities with autogenerated keys with default values will be Added. In this case too, calling the method twice won't have any effect.

Comment: @ArenDevel EF works in a *very* different way from the code you have now, so you can't just keep the existing code. EF is an ORM, not an UPSERT generator. It works at a higher level than individual object INSERTs and UPDATEs. If you want to keep the existing data access patterns, it's better to *not* use EF Core. It would be better to use a microORM like Dapper to reduce the boilerplate ADO.NET Code. EF Core's job is to remove the need for `InsertItemAsync` entirely

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I was afraid that'd be the case even though I did not want to admit it. Thank you for the answer even if it was to confirm my nightmare ;).

Comment: You're trying to use a high level framework as a low level data access library. It's a bit like using Razor Pages to generate and emit raw HTML strings. Yes, you can do it with some effort, but that's very wasteful. You can make EF Core act like ADO.NET, but to really take advantage of it, it has to work *above* those `Insert` methods

Comment: Yeah, I get it. We'll have to change the existing codebase, it was something we were hoping to avoid but if we want to migrate to EF, we need to. Thank you for your time.